# A question about orthogonal projections of an arc in 3-dimensional Euclidean space onto a plane

Tags: general-topology

Let E(3) be 3-dimensional Euclidean space with its standard metric and let P be a fixed plane subset of E(3). Does there exist an arc S, which is a subset of E(3) and whose orthogonal projection onto P is the set of all points of a (non-degenerate) square?

Comment: When you say "square", do you mean a 2D region (an area), or the four lines that form the outline of such a region??

Comment: I mean a 2D region.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you accepted the answer below. It gives a curve that forms the outline of a square region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Look at the cubic curve defined by 
\begin{align}
x(t) &= t \\
y(t) &= 2t^3 - 3 t^2 + t\\
z(t) &= 0
\end{align}
This arc --- call it $\gamma_1$ --- in 3-space projects (along $y$, to the $xz$ plane) to the straight-line arc that goes from $(0,0, 0)$ to $(1, 0, 0)$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Swapping some terms, as in 
\begin{align}
z(t) &= 1\\
y(t) &= 2t^3 - 3 t^2 + t\\
x(t) &= t 
\end{align}
gives a path $\gamma_2$ whose projection along $y$ goes from $(1,0,0)$ to $(1,0,1)$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$. Substituting $t-1$ for $t$ gives a path $\zeta_2$ that traverses the same segment as $t$ goes from $1$ to $2$.

Reversing $\gamma_1$, and adding $1$ to $z$, gives and arc whose projection along $y$ goes from 
$(1,0,1)$ to $(1,0,0)$. Substituting $t-2$ for $t$ givese $\zeta_3$ that traverses that segment as $t$ goes from $2$ to $3$.

And reversing and substituting in $\gamma_2$ gives a fourth arc $\zeta_4$ whose projection along $y$ traverses the last side of the square.

The curve
$$
\gamma(t) = \begin{cases} \gamma_1(t) & 0 \le t \le 1 \\
\zeta_2(t) & 1 \le t \le 2 \\
\zeta_3(t) & 2 \le t \le 3 \\
\zeta_4(t) & 3 \le t \le 4 \end{cases}
$$
gives a $C^1$ curve whose projection along $y$ traverses the square in the $xz$ plane.

To do the same thing for any other plane...follow the curve $\gamma$ with a translation and rotation that takes the unit square in the $xz$ plane to the unit square in the desired plane.

By the way, the thing I used to define $\gamma_1$ is called "Bezier segment", and I've just created a Bezier spline in 3-space.

Also: all you asked for was an "arc", but I figured I'd give you a $C^1$ arc; otherwise, the answer is "just take the arc that traverses the square itself at constant speed (but makes very sharp turns at the corners)."

Comment: @ John Hughes: That is very nice. I was trying to solve the problem by getting a countable subset of my arc to project onto a dense subset of the square, but I was getting nowhere.